# Relation between svg and php/apache requests

Tags: javascript, css, svg, graphics, hosting

Hi I was wondering what is the relation between SVG and the increase in PHP/ apache server requests which will lead some images not to load (the SVG elements are associated with CSS and JS to edit them)

Here is a page of my website were some images won't load sometimes
I know that I should upgrade hosting service but why does the SVG increase the requests while jpg and PNG doesn't?

https://easy-learning.ml/Math/math.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

As stated in the error message, you are using free hosting. Try switch to some thing else:

- Try their premium plan.
- Buy VPS, linode/vultr, etc.
- Try Heroku container.

### ref:

- http://linode.com/
- https://www.vultr.com/
- http://heroku.com/

Comment: I know that but i want to know why the proccess increase when adding svg images but won't increase if another type example:jpg,png

Comment: @Ahmed I looked `https://easy-learning.ml/Fixed-Designs/Math/dist2/images/` and I find the failed images are there. I tried several times, some are loaded, some are not, I just have to try more times. So I conclude that: the server is not stable enough. I still recommend that you buy a vps, instead of struggling in "free" service. They cost tooooo much (time).

Comment: I am new to programming and I can't buy a server until I am sure of my success 
i was asking if there was another option

Comment: for example using another free server for images only that will help

Comment: but i am asking for the relation why svg increase the requests while jpg and png doesn't increase it

Comment: all jpg and png images load well

Answer (score 0):

Images need to load before you initialize the `<Image>`. If you are loading an image through JavaScript, you have to put a onload event to allow it to load first before you do anything else.

Comment: can you please show me an example of the required code